# Custom linking with HTML

Tags: html

I've visited some sites and I have noticed that their links are different from others (or mines).

Example: "custom" link name: http://domain.com/faq

And my link would look like: http://domain.com/faq.php or faq.htm(l)

Question is: how can I get that kind of link with the use of HTML(5)?

I don't know how to search this problem, cause I don't know what name it would fit, I searched for custom links but it wasn't what I needed.

Comment: Its not really clear what you're asking.  Are you asking about the difference between domains, ie .com .org etc, file types (html, php), or URL patterns (domain.com, domain.com/faq)?

Comment: These are called Semantic URLs (or sometimes Clean URLs, or SEO friendly URLs). If your PHP is being run on an Apache environment, you will need to add Rewrite Rules to your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this :

```
RewriteRule ^faq$ faq.php [L]
```